# Using 'cron' module in node.js on heroku server

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron

I am using cron in node.js to schedule a function that sends text messages at user-determined times. It works on my local server, but when i deploy to heroku the functions never get called.

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippets that we need in order to help you diagnose and fix the problem.  Also, you should read this short SO help page:  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

I'll elaborate a little bit more on what @rsp said above, so that if anyone else finds this question they'll understand why using [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler) is the correct answer here.

When you're running software on Heroku, what happens is that Heroku will take your project, and run it on a random dyno (server) in the Heroku collection of servers on Amazon.

For a number of reasons (including to help distribute application load evenly across a large number of Amazon servers), Heroku will periodically move your dyno from one Amazon server to another. This happens many times per day, automatically, behind the scenes.

This means that your application code will be periodically restarting all the time when running on Heroku.

Now -- this isn't a bad thing from an end-user perspective, because while your application code is restarting, Heroku will queue up incoming requests, then just send them to your application once it's been successfully restarted on a new host. So to the end user, this behavior is 100% transparent.

What's important to know here, though, is that since your application code may randomly restart, you shouldn't use it to do things like run long tasks that take a while to finish, or queue up jobs to be executed in the future (what the cron module does).

Instead: Heroku created a free scheduler addon that you can use to basically say "Hey Heroku, run this Node script every minute|hour|etc."

The scheduler addon Heroku provides will reliably execute your cron task because Heroku keeps track of that timing stuff separately (outside of your application logic).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Would I be able to allow users to schedule tasks with this add-on? Currently my code schedules tasks based on what users enter through a form. Thanks.

Comment: You could not. If that's your use case, you should probably look into using a queueing service like RabbitMQ or Amazon SQS. The way this works in that case is that your application will send off a message to a queue (SQS / RabbitMQ / Redis / etc.), and then you'll have a separate process running (a worker dyno) which processes that task when needed. This is a more 'scalable' solution for the sort of use case you're describing.

Comment: @rdegges great explanation. One of the best I have seen on StackOverflow, great job!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a cron job on heroku with node. Here is my top level stuff

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

var dailyJob = new CronJob({
      cronTime: '0 0 0 * * *',
      onTick: function () {
        // Do daily function
        console.log('I get called 1 time a day.');
      },
      start: false
    });

dailyJob.start();
```

Comment: Does cron jobs work on heroku server for sure?

Comment: Yes. You would need to be on a tier that doesn't sleep.

Answer (score 0):

On Heroku you may need to use the Heroku Scheduler.

See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler